# Can you prove that the difference of these two undecidable sets is un/decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, decidability

I'm just an amateur programmer so please bear with me

consider the following sets of numbers
$$
D=\{m|\text{$m$ is a turing machine and does not halt on blank input}\}
$$
$$
G=\{m|\text{$m$ is a turing machine and does not halt on $m$}\}
$$
$$
L=D-G
$$

how can I prove that $L$ is un/decidable? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a TM $M$, we can construct a TM M' running the following program:

1. If the current cell is blank, GOTO 1
2. Simulate M

We find that $M' \in D \setminus G$ iff $M \notin G$. Thus, if $D \setminus G$ were decidable, so would be $G$. But $G$ is a standard variant of the Halting problem, and so we already know that $G$ is undecidable.

Comment: you mean there is a function $f$ such that $G(M)=L(f(M))$ ?

Comment: @raoof It's not mapping $G$ into $L$, but the complement of $G$.

Comment: like $G(M)=1-L(f(M))$ ? but is $f$ computable?

Comment: @raoof Sure, the construction is in the answer.

Comment: how do you prove that $L$ is/not recursively enumerable?